# Are fundamental representations of Lie algebras faithful?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $L$ be a semisimple algebra, $\alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_l$ a base of the root system $\Phi$,  $\omega_1, \cdots, \omega_l$ the dual basis relative to the inner product (such that
$ \langle \omega_i, \alpha_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}$). Is the irreducible representation $L(\omega_k)$ of highest weight $\omega_k$ faithful?

Comment: This should be true iff $L$ is simple. Otherwise I think each fundamental representation should be a faithful representation of exactly one of the simple factors of $L$.

Comment: Thanks! Can you prove that, or find an example of a non faithful fundamental representation of a semisimple algebra?

Comment: It should follow from the observation that when you take the direct sum of two semisimple Lie algebras the simple roots are just the disjoint union of the simple roots of the summands. (I'm hedging a little here because I haven't worked much with fundamental weights so I'm not as fluent here as I'd like to be.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes, the fundamental weights "live" in their individual connected components of the dynkin diagram (since we know we can get fundamental weights without using any extra simple roots, and the inner product with anything from outside is already $0$). In general, if $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are weights coming from different components, then $L(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)$ will be the external tensor product $L(\lambda_1)\boxtimes L(\lambda_2)$ where the factors are irreducibles for the corresponding summands.

Comment: Now whether the $L(\omega_i)$ are faithful when the Lie algebra is simple, I have not actually thought about, but that does seem plausible (might even be some well-known statement that I just forgot about for the moment).

Comment: @Tobias: a nontrivial representation of a simple Lie algebra is necessarily faithful.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Ahh, right. Should wake up more before writing things :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments: this is true iff $L$ is simple. Writing $L$ as the direct sum of its simple factors $L_i$, the simple roots of $L$ are the disjoint union of the simple roots of each $L_i$, and similarly for the fundamental weights. So the fundamental representations of $L$ are the fundamental representations of each $L_i$, and in particular they are faithful representations of exactly one of the simple factors of $L$ at a time.